# jQuery Handlers Not Working in Word Press

Tags: jquery, wordpress

**Edit - I removed the code from my header file and tried the instructions from https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

I added this code in my functions file

```
function shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery');
```

I see a successful GET request in the console to the CDN. I also tried changing the link to https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js from the official jquery site

I have a file named main.js with this code -

```
(function ($) {
  console.log("working");

  $(".about-text").click(function () {
    alert("test")
  });

})(jQuery);
```

The "working" console log shows so it know that is is loaded, but the jQuery handler for the click does not. I've also tried hover() and that is not working, also tried just  -

```
$(".about-text).hide()
```

This is the div I am testing -

```
    <div class="about-text">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <h3><?php the_content(); ?></h3>
    </div>
```

I also added

```
<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>
```

and

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

(example from the jquery.com site) and it is not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have any content blocker which blocks `alert()`? try with `console.log` instead and also try with `$("body").on("click",".about-text",function(){`

Comment: Tried that, still not working

Comment: try with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  $( "#target" ).click(function() {   alert( "Handler for .click() called." ); });   }`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: added in my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in WordPress jQuery is loaded in no conflict mode so you can't use `$` like that , instead you can use jQuery as below then you can use `$`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
    $( "#target" ).click(function() {   
       alert( "Handler for .click() called." ); 
    });   
}
```

or you have another option to use [no conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)  like

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function() {  
        j( "#target" ).click(function() {   
           alert( "Handler for .click() called." ); 
        });   
    }
```